# Can I add new vertices to an object on a per-keyframe basis?

Tags: animation, objects, vertices, keyframes

I would like to have a mesh 'grow', so to speak. For that, I need to be able to add vertices at certain keyframes.

I understand interpolation between keyframes would be difficult so for now, a frame by frame setup would suffice. So I would add new vertices to the object per frame.

Can this be done in Blender? Eventually, if at all possible, this will be done programmatically, but a UI based way to do it would be a great start!

EDIT: So, most likely this is not possible. That is great to know because it will save me a lot of searching and experimenting. I will look for different ways to achieve what I have in mind.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to change the geometry in the keyframes. A possible workaround could be, a) find out the maximum vertices that the mesh will have when it is fully 'grown' b) put some of the vertices at the same location depending on the desired mesh shape, at given keyframes.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks you for the suggestion. I thought about that aswel but it probably won't work with a subdivision modifier.

Comment: You could try 'growing' a model in stages.  When more vertices are required, duplicate the model at that point and switch over to it. Add as many vertices as you can on that one. Animate it's growth from there.

Comment: Thanks, I will probably do something like that :)

Comment: Have a look at this [shapekey answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/111139/30849).

Comment: Maybe use a mask modifier?

Comment: Thanks. I already checked shapekeys but that's not going to work for my situation. I think the mask modifier could theoretically be a possibility, I don't know if it can be done in a relatively easy way. I will definitely consider though.

Comment: @DionSnoeijen, the counterpart of the mask is to set vertex group weights appropriately and main issue is the "open geometry" you may have until vertices appear.

Comment: You could try to use Build modifier as one option in addition to mentioned above, sorting vertices could help it make vertices appear in some certain way. That said, technically it's not actually building mesh but hiding it first and revealing instead. You could also look into curves (they have Start and End options) or addons like Animation Nodes which can more or less achieve what you ask. Probably someone could provide a workaround if you share the mesh / screenshots to be animated

Comment: For now, I went with a new mesh per step. It works as I wanted. It's just a lot of meshes :).